# Unable to pipsi install pew

Tags: python, path, virtualenv

I have installed pipsi through `$ curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mitsuhiko/pipsi/master/get-pipsi.py | python3`

I have brew installed python2 and python3:

```
echo $PATH
/Users/joseph/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
which pipsi
/Users/joseph/.local/bin/pipsi

pipsi install pew
Traceback (most recent call last):
  **long lines of tracebacks**
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'virtualenv': 'virtualenv'

which virtualenv
virtualenv not found
```

I understand that the installation of pipsi comes with its own virtualenv which is located in `Users/joseph/.local/venvs/pipsi/bin/virtualenv`

I found [this](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/pipsi/issues/89) online:

1. Have pipsi symlink its virtualenv into the bin_dir.
2. Have pipsi use a cross-platform wrapper to activate the virtualenv when running a linked script. (activate-wrapper)
3. Have pipsi specifically look up its own virtualenv. (pipsi-virtualenv)

I have not applied the methods shown above.  I believe that the third method is the closest to what I need, but I don't even know if editing the pipsi file is what I need to do.  I wanted to ask the community for advice.
Why am I getting the FileNotFoundError?

#### Long lines of tracebacks per @Bryan Zeng:

```
File "/Users/joseph/.local/bin/pipsi", line 11, in <module>
  load_entry_point('pipsi==0.9', 'console_scripts', 'pipsi')()
File "/Users/joseph/.local/venvs/pipsi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
  return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/joseph/.local/venvs/pipsi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 697, in main
  rv = self.invoke(ctx)
File "/Users/joseph/.local/venvs/pipsi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
  return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
File "/Users/joseph/.local/venvs/pipsi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
  return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
File "/Users/joseph/.local/venvs/pipsi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
  return callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/joseph/.local/venvs/pipsi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 27, in new_func
  return f(get_current_context().obj, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/joseph/.local/venvs/pipsi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipsi.py", line 366, in install
  if repo.install(package, python, editable):
File "/Users/joseph/.local/venvs/pipsi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipsi.py", line 236, in install
  if Popen(args).wait() != 0:
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
  restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
  raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
```

Comment: I would like to see the "`**long lines of traceback**`".

Comment: @Bryan Zeng I have added them into the main question.

Comment: And yep. You need to edit it.

Comment: @BryanZeng what do you mean by edit it